# Vertical align causing highlight to overlap, making text illegible

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, pseudo-element

I have a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x44e72Lk/1/) using `:after` and `:before` to insert quotes.

The problem is when you highlight the entire paragraph, the highlight overlaps and makes some words illegible.

I need the quotes to be that size and in that position, is there a way to prevent the highlighting from making the text invisible?

Comment: First of all, this seems ok to me, it might be your browser that gives the problem. Secondly, why don't you just increase the word spacing a big so it doesn't overlap. Can you attach a screenshot so I can have a better preview of how you see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `dipslay: inline-block` to both `after` and `before` and there you go!

```css
p:before{
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  content: '“';
  margin-right: 0.125em;
}
p:after{
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  content: '”';
  margin-left: 0.125em;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, novum errem perfecto id qui, esse antiopam cu sea, eum veniam soleat delicatissimi id. Impedit probatus in sit, quem abhorreant mnesarchum eos ad. Id erat equidem ius. Ne mel scaevola oporteat percipitur, id zril diceret commune cum. Ut mea quodsi labores assentior, populo explicari pro ea. 
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply! Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know `inline-block` would fix it

Comment: Could you explain why adding `display: inline-block` fixes the issue ?

Comment: well, that's hard to explain! but I guess to put it *simple* - the subtle difference is because of the fact that `height` calculated by UA of `inline-block` is its margin-box while for `inline` it is the `line-height` property